# Finding the momentum of a muon in $\pi\to\mu\nu_\mu$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, energy, momentum

> The $\pi$-meson's mass is 139.57 MeV, and it decays into a muon and a neutrino.
>   The muon has a mass of 105.4 5MeV, and a proper lifetime of $2.197 \times 10^{-6}$. The neutrino can be treated as massless in this process.
>
> *Assuming the $\pi$-meson decays at rest, what is the momentum of the
>   muon?*
>
> Relevant equations from [this resource](https://teachers.web.cern.ch/teachers/archiv/HST2002/Bubblech/mbitu/energy_and_momentum_conservation1.htm):
>   $$E_{\mu} = c^2 \left[ \frac{m_{\pi}^2 + m_{\mu}^2}{2m_{\pi}}\right] \tag{2.5}$$
>   $$E_{\mu} = \sqrt{p_{\mu}^2 c^2 + m_{\mu}^2 c^4}$$

I used the first equation and it gives about $E_{\mu}=9.866 \times 10^{18}$, then, used this value in the 2nd equation and solving for the momentum, I get a negative value under the square root, which doesn't make sense. In the 1st equation, the values I plugged in for $m_{\pi}$ and $m_{\mu}$ are just 139.57 and 105.47, and used $3 \times 10^8$ for $c$. Where did I go wrong?

The the first equation used here is based on the conservation of momentum. For the second equation, we know that $E^2 = p^2 c^2 + m^2 c^4$, so I took the square root of both sides to get $E$, and from there I tried to find the momentum $p_\mu$ using the mass of the muon and the energy $E_\mu$ of the muon found from the first equation.

Comment: Though we want to no what equations used I always encourage people to talk about *principles* before formulas. What principle(s) are you applying here? How do those principles relate to the expressions you've written down? Are those expressions complete and correct?

Comment: Additional questions: what kind of unit is a $\mathrm{MeV}$ anyway? (Hint: it's not a SI unit.) Does it make sense to use it as a mass? Why or why not? What value should be assigned to the speed of light in the system of units where masses are measured in $\mathrm{MeV}$?

Comment: @dmckee I really thought my main problem was my units, so I should use kg instead of MeV, and that would work with the speed of light assigned as 3*10^8 m/s ?

Comment: Particle physics is typically done in "natural units" meaning that the speed of light and the reduced plank's constant have both been set to one: $c = \hbar = 1 \,\text{(dimensionless)}$. Now, $\mathrm{MeV}$ is an energy unit. Momentum must be energy divided by velocity (and in fact by $c$), so $\mathrm{MeV}/c$; mass must be $\mathrm{MeV}/c^2$ and so on. Only $c=1$, so we leave it off and just remember what kind of quantity each symbol is. If you want to work in $\mathrm{MeV}$ (and all the cool kids do), you set $c=1$. Try it again. *Then* try it in SI units to see if you get the same answer.

Comment: @dmckee still it gives a negative under the root. I think my process is wrong, but I just found the specific equation for this problem in my notes now and tried those units, and it worked! answer is 29.95 MeV, thanks for your help

Comment: Ah ... you appear to have a transcription error. Look again at the sign on the top of (2.5). And BTW, we usually write just $m_\mu$ and $m_\pi$. Saves typing and looks neater.

Comment: Yes, @dmckee is right. Look again at Eq. 2.5 (you have a mistake, I think) and be careful with units. At first, $c=1$ units can be confusing, but it actually makes things much simpler once you are familiar with it.

Comment: You should now be able to do this question, I think. If you manage, I suggest that you answer your own question here, for others to see.